# enter value and click search in url with powershell

Tags: powershell

i hope everyone is well, i'm asking about possibility to send value in url and click buton send with powershell, i was search for it but I'm not good on web, it is to integrate a function into a tool to verify the authenticity of the ISO

url : [www.heidoc.net](http://www.heidoc.net)
sha1 value for exemple : 0E02044A25F830EF5F1DE335DFE16370B000D12F

can someone help me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can verify the authenticity of an ISO *(or any other)* file once it is downloaded by using a SHA checksum.

There is a native functionality in PowerShell for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash?view=powershell-5.1

**Usage:**

```
Get-FileHash -Path Get-FileHash C:\Users\user1\Downloads\Contoso8_1_ENT.iso -Algorithm SHA256
```

---

If you want to get the hash from a file on the internet in 1 step, the same article has an example using `WebClient` from the .Net Framework:

**Usage:**

```
$wc = [System.Net.WebClient]::new()
$pkgurl = 'https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/download/v6.2.4/powershell_6.2.4-1.debian.9_amd64.deb'
$publishedHash = '8E28E54D601F0751922DE24632C1E716B4684876255CF82304A9B19E89A9CCAC'
$FileHash = Get-FileHash -InputStream ($wc.OpenRead($pkgurl))
$FileHash.Hash -eq $publishedHash
```

Here we have:

`$pkgurl` is the URI/URL of the file *(iso in your case)*
`$publishedHash` is the HASH you expect the file to have

The WebClient will connect and verify the hash of the file against the `$publishedHash` you have provided and will either return `True` or `False`.

Comment: hi, thank you for reply, it is not exactly the same thing that i want, to get as information, i want check and display for wich windows ISO version SHA1 is matche, i was do it from analyzing the result page and compare the source code from generated page and result, to get these result